# ES2015/2016 way of 'typeof varName === 'undefined`?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I'm wallowing in ES2015+ luxury with a few projects right now and am wondering whether I can get rid of the much hated crutch to check for `undefined` in the new wonderland.

Is there a shorter but still exact way to `typeof varName === 'undefined'` in ES2015+ already?

Of course I could use [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) but this also feels like an unnecessary assignment.

```
function coolFn(a = null){
   if (a===null) console.log("no a supplied");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "better"?

Comment: Why use a typeof check in the first place? `if(a===undefined)`

Comment: @Pointy I meant shorter to write but still covering all cases.

Comment: why wouldn't you just check if( !a ) ?  I don't see why the value being null or undefined actually matters - whereas `a` actually having a value seems to be the true check.  that is - of course, unless you are going to allow for `false` or `0` to be valid values =P

Comment: Or `(a == null)` which covers both `null` and `undefined`.

Comment: @JonathonHibbard that's precisely why you'd want to make an explicit check for `=== undefined` !!

Comment: @Alnitak yeah - i gather that.  just thinking something as simple as a `!` might be all the guy really needs - but don't know for sure.

Comment: @JonathonHibbard  Your question being "why wouldn't you?".  Because the OP clearly wants to be able to distinguish the difference between the parameter being passed and an otherwise legal (but falsey) value.

Comment: i think you're assuming a lot by that @Alnitak - he never indicated that a `0` or `false`would be valid values... he also never indicated they would be either.  which is why i asked =P

Comment: He absolutely did indicate that the test is for a _missing value_ - it's there in the console log message `"No a supplied"`

Comment: plus there's the comment to my answer (pre-dating your first comment) saying that what I'd asked for was what he was looking for.  Oh, and the question title.

Comment: That doesn't "absolutely" mean that - not at all.  only the OP would know what is considered a "valid" value.  but assuming that `false` (or even `0`) is considered a valid value is a huge assumption

Comment: Assuming that `0` (or `false`) isn't a valid value is a worse assumption.

Comment: I agree @Alnitak - that's why i asked - rather than just `assuming` =)

Comment: Sorry for being unclear in the first place. I want to be able to distinguish undefined from false or an empty array.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Just check for `varName === undefined`.

In older browsers it was possible to assign an alternate value to the global `undefined` variable causing that test to fail, but in ES2015+ that's now impossible.

Note that there's no way to distinguish explicitly passing `undefined` as a parameter from leaving the parameter out altogether other than by looking at `arguments.length`.

Comment: How could I miss that! Yeah, that's already good enough :) I don't need to distinguish between both cases you mentioned.

Comment: Since ES5 you can't alter the global `undefined` property. But you can still shadow it with a local variable.

Comment: @Oriol that's true, but if you do that you've only got yourself to blame.  What you can't do now is "inject" a different value of `undefined` into the global scope.

Comment: Isn't the inability to redefine `undefined` a matter of `"use strict;"` rather than ES2015?

Comment: @torazaburo not to my knowledge

Comment: @torazaburo [Annex E](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-E) of ES5 lists "The value properties NaN, Infinity, and undefined of the Global Object have been changed to be read-only properties" as an incompatibility with ES3. So the change affects non-strict mode too.

Comment: The following could still cause trouble: `function foo(undefined) { return function bar(a) { console.log(a === undefined); }; }  console.log(foo(42)());`.

Comment: @torazaburo yes, that's what Oriol was referring to by "shadowing".  That's mere "programmer error", though, whereas allowing the overwriting of the global `undefined` property could potentially lead to security problems.

Comment: Please keep in mind that `varName === undefined` will throw a `ReferenceError` if the variable is not defined.

Answer (score 25):

The only case where `typeof varName === 'undefined'` is useful is when you don't know whether the variable `varName` has been declared.

And IMO if you don't know whether your variables are declared, your code has serious problems.

In other cases you have better options:

- `varName === void 0`

  This will detect whether `varName` is undefined.

  `void` is an operator which receives an argument (you can use whatever instead of `0`), and returns undefined.
- `varName === undefined`

  This *should* detect whether `varName` is undefined.

  However, be aware the global `undefined` could have been overwritten (before ES5) or shadowed with another value. Therefore I prefer `void`, which is also shorter.
- `varName == null`

  This will detect whether `varName` is undefined or is null.
- `!varName`

  This will detect whether `varName` is falsy (undefined, null, 0, empty string, NaN, false).

Comment: `void 0` is nice, but a bit of an odd syntax since `void` has barely any other use in JS (if any?) and doesn't quite express the desired intent.

Comment: If you want shorter, `[][0]` is shorter than `void 0`.

Comment: @TravisJ Unless some mad script did `Array.prototype[0] = someThing` ;)

Comment: @Oriol - Of course, that makes sense. Perhaps use 8 then ;) `[][8]`.

Comment: One reasonable use is detecting if code is running within a browser or within node. `typeof window === 'undefined'` is true when running in node, false when running in  browser.