# TS2538 Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type. when check assigned to variable

Tags: javascript, typescript

I get TS error:

> TypeScript error: Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type.  TS2538

For this simple function (getting object from array based on provided index):

```js
const myArr: Array<object> = [{name: 'John'}, {name: 'Tom'}]

function getData(index?: number) {
    const isIndex : boolean = typeof index !== 'undefined';

    return isIndex ? myArr[index] : {};
}
```

What's more mysterious for me is that when I change it to:

```
function getData(index?: number) {
    return typeof index !== 'undefined' ? myArr[index] : {};
}
```

Everything works like a charm - why?

Comment: It seems to be a problem with extrapolating the code path. In the latter case it's absolutely clear that if `index` is `undefined`, then you would not take the code path that does  `myArr[index]`. When you introduce the level of indirection from the first example, it's not immediately clear that `myArr[index]` will not be called when `index` is `undefined`.

Comment: This is the way code analysis works, if you do the check inline it can follow the logic and narrow the variable if you put it in a variable it will not be able to follow the logic.

Answer (score 3):

Typescript will not perform code analysis as expected due to an indirection in the code flow. This is when *User Defined Type Guards* come in to save the day.

```
function isUndefined(index: any): index is boolean {
    return typeof index === "undefined";
}

function getData(index?: number) {
    return isUndefined(index) ? {} : myArr[index];
}
```

Because index is optional in the `getData` method, it is possible that it will be `undefined`, your second technique works.

Comment: aren't you returning a correct value from an array when it's undefined, and embty object when it's defined?

Answer (score 1):

Type guards don't work with intermediate variables. You have to directly test the variable:

```
function getData(index?: number) {
  return index !== undefined ? myArr[index] : {};
}
```

Or:

```
function getData(index?: number) {
  if (index === undefined)
    return {};
  return myArr[index]
}
```

See also: [documentation from the handbook on **type guards**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types).

Notice: `typeof index !== 'undefined'` is not required nowadays: [ES2015/2016 way of 'typeof varName === 'undefined`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34596489/es2015-2016-way-of-typeof-varname-undefined)

Comment: `typeof index !== 'undefined'` is not even needed here. The variable `index` is *by definition* present - you'd want to do the `typeof` check to avoid referencing an undefined variable. The other problem that `typeof` solves is `undefined` is...not actually the value `undefined`. I'd say that if you have *that* problem, then there is something bigger that's amiss and `typeof` is just treating the symptom, not the problem.

Comment: As a side note, you can still redefine `undefined` even with strict mode. I was surprised to find this out, honestly. `test = undefined => "a" == undefined` and then try calling `test("a")`

Comment: @VLAZ My bad it is since ES2015. Yes you can name a parameter `undefined` but it is just a bad practice. The user of your API can't change your `undefined`, it is enough to write strong code.