# Why does undefined cannot be used as an index type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, undefined

My question is not about the meaning of the meaning of the

> Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type

typescript error, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56355117/8186898) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43836274/8186898) - I know that it happens when doing `someObject[someValueThatMightBeUndefined]`.

Rather, I want to know why TypeScript prevents this, as `undefined` can be used to index objects:

```js
const foo = {}
foo[undefined] = 10
foo[undefined] // 10
```

My best guess is that using `undefined` as a key is a *bad idea* because `undefined` and `'undefined'` are not the same, yet these

```js
foo[undefined]
foo['undefined']
foo.undefined
```

point to the same property. But I'm not entirely satisfied with this answer because TypeScript should prevent code that breaks, not bad code.

Comment: If you really want to do this with TypeScript, just use `foo['undefined']` then. As you've pointed out yourself, this is the same as `foo[undefined]`.

Comment: They point to the same property because keys that are neither strings nor symbols are converted to strings. This is a fact of life in JavaScript and TypeScript wants you to be explicit since accidentally indexing with such a value is a source of bugs. If you actually want to have a key that _is_ the `undefined` value, you can must a `Map`.